# Winter Bash link should refer to the full site when mobile web doesn’t have hats

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, mobile-web, winter-bash

The mobile web doesn’t have any hats, and when I was notified on the full site (MSE) about a new hat,

> [image: mse-full-hat]

clicking on it refers me to the mobile version of Stack Overflow due to my settings. But there are no hats on mobile web:

> [image: so-no-hats-mobile]

This behavior is slightly confusing. I think the full site version should be used in this case.

Comment: Switching from the mobile site to the full site, or vice versa, is quite common (e.g. with some of the badge notifications, or new privilege notifications). It's going to be hard to develop something to support this.

Comment: @Glorfindel exactly. Some pages don’t have mobile version, and I would like to add winter bash hat selection page to the such list. E.g. don’t open mobile profile page with no hats, open separate full web page for it.

Comment: @alexolut The problem is that there isn't a separate page for Winter Bash. It's the profile page, and the full version just happens to have extra stuff on it. There's no way around that. Displaying it as a full site if some sort of Winter bash variable is present in the URL is just more effort than it's really worth considering you only need to switch to full site *once* on a new site and the setting sticks. Problem solved.